# Custom controllers in UserFrosting

Tags: php, slim, userfrosting

I have been trying to create a custom controller that extends **UserFrosting**'s **BaseController** and then call it's method from *index.php*. Seems simple, but so far I am highly unsuccessful. I am new to UserFrosting, hence I am most likely missing something obvious.

**controllers/LGController.php:**

```
<?php
namespace UserFrosting;
class LGController extends \UserFrosting\BaseController {
    public function __construct($app){
        $this->_app = $app;
    }

    public function lgRequestsList(){
        $groups = array('Luke #1', 'Luke #2');
            $this->_app->render('lg-request-list.twig', [
                "groups" => $groups
            ]);
    }
}
```

**index.php:**

```
...
    use UserFrosting as UF;

    $app->get('/lg/requests/?', function () use ($app) {
        $controller = new UF\LGController($app);
        return $controller->lgRequestsList();
    }); 
...
```

**Error:**

```
[Wed Nov 09 15:25:40 2016] [warn] [client 160.34.126.11] mod_fcgid: stderr: Fatal error (1) in /home2/test/public_html/index.php on line 66: Class 'UserFrosting\\LGController' not found, referer: http://xxx.co.uk/groups/g/1/auth
```

Comment: and the error is?

Comment: also.. you don't need the constructor as it will be inherited from the base controller.. you need a custom constructor only if you have custom properties for your class

Comment: Do you have the controller included?

Comment: do you mean php's include()?

Comment: yep thats what I wrote.

Comment: There was a wrong path in the include. MANY THANKS. All good now :)

Comment: do NOT use `include`.  UserFrosting uses Composer to autoload classes.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `include` to include your new controller class.  UserFrosting uses [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to autoload your files.

Once you [install Composer globally](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx), all you need to do is run `composer dump-autoload` in your `userfrosting/` subdirectory, and it will add the new class for you.